# Как правильно закрыть файл?

Tags: c++, файлы

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как правильно закрыть файл в данной функции? При частом вызывании функции  выдаются серьезные ошибки `“Error opening file: Too many open files”`

```
int urez(){    
  int fh;
  fh=open("d:\\1.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
  chsize(fh,2);

  /*
  как правильно закрыть файл? fclose(???)    
  fclose(fh); --- не работает
  */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Тема закрыта! Разобрался сам. 
Кому интересно правильный ответ " close(fh); "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

close(fh);

Для fopen() fclose(), для popen() pclose(), для opendir() closedir(), для open() и socket() close().

Вообще, внимательно смотрите на типы результатов функций и **SEE ALSO** в man.

Answer (score -1):

лучше используйте std::ifstream, std::ofstream. с ними как-то проще всё..

Answer (score -1):

Нужно использовать файловую переменную, т.е.

```
FILE *fh;
//И потом так:
fh = fopen("d:\1.txt", "rt");
```

Нас в универе учили так :)

Comment: Ну и учителя ...

Comment: А что не так-то?